# Why does this function return false in React Native?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, google-cloud-firestore

**funciton**

```js
checkIfSeen = (uid, news_id) => {
  var seen = false;
  const docRef = DB.informationsCollection.doc(news_id).collection('users').doc(uid);
  docRef.get()
    .then((docSnapshot) => {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        seen = true;
        console.log(seen);
        // returns true
      }
    });
  console.log(seen);
  // returns false
}
```

**Problem**

It returns true after `if (docSnapshot.exists) {` but returns false in the last of the function.

Does anybody know why this happens?

I would appreciate it if you could give me any adivce.

**updated**

```js
checkIfSeen = (uid, news_id) => {
  const docRef = Fire.shared.informationsCollection.doc(news_id).collection('users').doc(uid);
  docRef.get()
    .then((docSnapshot) => {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        this.alreadySeen();
      } else {
        this.notSeen();
      }
    });
}

alreadySeen = () => {
  return true;
}

notSeen = () => {
  return false;
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Answer (score 0):

The function `checkIfSeen` has no explicit return type. It will always return `undefined` to who ever calls it.

And also there is an asynchronous activity inside the function, at `docRef.get()`

This is something called as a promise. It executes the `then` block when its job is done passing the returned data to the function supplied to the `then` function.

The function execution now enters then block and it cannot synchronously return to the outer function.

You can continue execution of your program inside the then function. like

```
checkIfSeen = (uid, news_id) => {
  var seen = false;
  const docRef = DB.informationsCollection.doc(news_id).collection('users').doc(uid);
  docRef.get()
    .then((docSnapshot) => {
      if (docSnapshot.exists) {
        seen = true;

        // Do something here or invoke any other function
        renderUI();
        console.log(seen);
        // returns true
      }
    });
  console.log(seen);
  // returns false
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I added the updated code, but it returns undefined :( I would appreciate it if you could check it.